# FFT Speed on Noncubic meshes

Tags: python, performance, fft, fftw, pyfftw

I need to repeatedly take the Fourier Transform/Inverse Fourier Transform of a 3d function in order to solve a differential equation. Something like:

```
import pyfftw.interfaces.numpy_fft as fftw
for i in range(largeNumber):
    fFS = fftw.rfftn(f)
    # Do stuff
    f = fftw.irfftn(fFS)
```

The shape of f is highly noncubic. Is there any performance difference based on the order of dimensions, for example (512, 32, 128) vs (512, 128, 32), etc.?

I am looking for any speed ups available. I have already tried playing around with wisdom. I thought it might be fastest if the largest dimension went last (e.g. 32, 128, 512) so that fFS.shape = (32, 128, 257), but this doesn't appear to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to squeeze all the performance out you can, use the FFTW object directly (most easily accessed through `pyfftw.builders`). This way you get careful control over exactly what copies occur and whether the normalization is performed on inverse.

Your code as-is will likely benefit from using the cache (enabled by calling `pyfftw.interfaces.cache.enable()`), which minimises the set up time for the general and safe case, though doesn't eliminate it.

Regarding the best arrangement of dimensions, you'll have to suck it and see. Try all the various options and see what is fastest (with `timeit`). Make sure when you do the tests you're actually using the data arranged in memory as expected and not just taking a view of the same array in memory (which `pyfftw` may well handle fine without a copy - though there are tweak parameters for this sort of thing).

`FFTW` tries lots of different options (different algorithms over different FFT representations) and picks the fastest, so you end up with non-obvious implementations that may well change for different datasets that are superficially very similar.

General tips:

- Turn on the multi-threading for maximum performance (set `threads=N` where appropriate).
- Make sure your arrays are suitably byte aligned - this has less impact than it used to with modern hardware, but will probably make a difference (particularly if all your higher dimension sizes have the byte alignment as a factor).
- Read the [tutorial](http://hgomersall.github.io/pyFFTW/sphinx/tutorial.html) and the [api docs](http://hgomersall.github.io/pyFFTW/sphinx/api.html).